# Change DataGridViewCell user input handling behavior

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, timespan

I have a winform app with a TimeSpan column that displays the hours/minutes part of a date.  When the user enters text it is converted to a TimeSpan using `TimeSpan.TryParse()`.  This works as expected when the user input is "11:00" in setting a value of 11 hours.  The problem is that if the use enters "1100" it is parsed as 1100 days which is not what I want, nor is simply saying "bad input" in the `CellValidating event satisfactory behavior.

The users input is provided in the readonly property `DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs.FormattedValue` so I can't change the value being passed through the call chain.  `DataGridViewTextBoxCell.EditedFormattedValue` is also read only and I can't find any other event or property that lets override the default behavior.

This is very frustrating.  I can write a many stepped fall through validater that can handle multiple user input formats and get the intended value from each; but unless I throw away all the strongly typed data binding that the framework offers and instead create a shim object that stores all values as strings there doesn't seem to be any way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow among the 10 billion events in the DataGridView I managed to overlook [`CellParsing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellparsing.aspx).  Overriding it lets me do what I need to do.